# Show that a system has no limit cycle

Tags: nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

$\dot{x_1} = -x_1(1 - x_1^2 - x_2^2)$,  $\dot{x_2} = -x_2(1 - x_1^2 - x_2^2)$

The question is to prove this system has no limit cycle.

I changed to polar co-ordinates to get:
$\dot{r} = -r(1-r^2) , \dot{\theta} = 0 $

Can any conclusions be made from here?

Comment: Do you consider your question answered or do you have more questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Gerhard S’s comment, can you have a limit cycle when $\dot{\theta}=0$?

My original comment on $r$ dynamics, based on having read your question as $\dot{\theta}=1$ was referring to the fact that $r=1$ would have been an *unstable* limit cycle.  (See comments below).

Note: what you have is a circle of unstable fixed points, not a limit cycle.

Comment: What does $\dot\theta=0$ tell you?

Comment: @Moo thanks, but if neither the writer, nor the reader can see the LaTeX rendered, what does “supported” mean?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks, @Moo!

Comment: @GerhardS. - I'm getting an intuition that a "loop" isn't possible, but could you give some hint as to how to prove it mathematically that a limit cycle doesn't exist?

Comment: @Mathemagical - with respect to your original answer, could you explain what you were thinking of when you told me to check behaviour around $1$? As it's visible, $\dot{r}\ge0 , r\le1$ and $\dot{r}\le0 , r\ge1$. But what point is this driving? I'm confused.

Comment: @Mathemagical - ignore previous comment. With respect to your original answer, could you explain what you were thinking of when you told me to check behaviour around $1$? As it's visible, $\dot{r}\le0 , r\le1$ and $\dot{r}\ge0 , r\ge1$. But what point is this driving? I'm confused.

Comment: Well, my point was that there is no *stable* limit cycle. If $\dot{theta}=1$ (which is how I first misread it), then the only candidate for a limit cycle, $r=1$, is unstable (other trajectories approach it as $t\rightarrow -\infty$, not as $t\rightarrow \infty$. In everyday terminology, we usually mean a stable limit cycle when we say “limit cycle”, but actually both types are limit cycles per definition.

Comment: I did not check your conversion to polar coordinates, but if $\theta$ is the angle and this angle does not change ($\dot\theta=0$), then I do not see a cycle.